# cron runs job at unexpected times

Tags: ssh, cron

I have set up a cron job on my local Ubuntu 12.04 server to log on a remote server through a passwordless ssh connection and run `mysqldump` on a database on that server once a day. My problem is that, in addition to running `mysqldump` at 00:00 every day, it is for some reason also run at HH:17 at every hour, thereby filling up the disk fairly rapidly. The job in my crontab is set up as:

```
@daily  /bin/bash /home/backup/scripts/db_backup
```

The most important parts of the script db_backup looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sets the properties and folders to be backed up
host_name=admin@the_host.com
db_name=the_db_name
db_backup_folder_at_host="~/db_backup"

# Dumps the mysql database
{ # Try
    ssh ${host_name} "mysqldump ${db_name} > ${db_backup_folder_at_host}/backup$(date +%F_%R).sql" &&
    echo "$(date) SUCCESS! mysqldump of database"
} || { # Catch
    echo "$(date) FAILURE! mysqldump of database"
}
```

At the remote server I have specified a `.my.cnf` file for the database (in the home folder) like this:

```
[mysqldump]
user=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
host=MYSQLSERVER
```

and this works fine.

The crontab is successfully installed for the super user of my local Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have tried rebooting the server, but that does not fix the problem. Running `sudo ps -A | grep cron` at the Ubuntu server produces `1166 ? 00:00:00 cron` as output, so only one process is running. Running `sudo crontab -l` shows the daily cron job above, while running `crontab -l` shows that no jobs are installed for the regular user. There are no cron jobs running on the remote server.

Can anyone give me a hint on how this can be happening? Where can I search for clues?

Note that I have also tried the following for the crontab, but `mysqldump` is still run every HH:17:

```
0 0 * * *   /bin/bash /home/backup/scripts/db_backup
```

Comment: Just came to my mind that I have not checked my /etc/cron.hourly file recently. I'll check that when I get back home.

Comment: My /etc/cron.hourly *directory* that is, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm running a different version of ubuntu, my /etc/crontab runs the hourly script 17mins past the hour.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Have a look in /etc/cron.hourly

Comment: Yup, that's it. Had an old version of the backup script in the /etc/cron.hourly folder. As a side note my /etc/crontab file in Ubuntu 12.04 looks the same as yours.